# Missing txn-current file in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, repository

My TortoiseSVN project was working fine until yesterday. But today when I tried to commit it, got below error message. I am pretty sure I haven't deleted that file myself. Any ideas to recover it / some other workaround?

TortoiseSVN 1.6.16, Build 21511 - 32 Bit , 2011/06/01 19:00:35
Subversion 1.6.17, 
apr 1.3.12
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011
zlib 1.2.5
I am running it on Windows-7. I have a dual-boot system (other OS Ubuntu)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: See the similar question and the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031544/empty-or-non-existent-db-txn-current-in-a-subversion-repository

Answer (score 3):

**Preface:** Using file:/// access-level for Subversion is always bad idea for any longer than *few transactions* task

**Face:** If you lost file, you have to repair it

> The "txn-current" file is a file with a single line of text that
>   contains only a base-36 number.  The current value will be used in the
>   next transaction name, along with the revision number the transaction
>   is based on.  This sequence number ensures that transaction names are
>   not reused, even if the transaction is aborted and a new transaction
>   based on the same revision is begun.

tells us [Subversion own repo](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure)

Recipe from accepted answer for ["svn commit problem, Cannot read 'd:\UC\db\txn-current': End of file found"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4570451) (`svnadmin verify` + `svnadmin recover`) is perfectly valid and usable also

Comment: Thanks .. I'm not able to understand what is meant by "file:/// access-level". What have I done wrong?  How to make it right? Also I can't find `svnadmin.exe` in my PC anywhere .. Should I reinstall tortoiseSVN?